# Foreach sum of textboxes c#

Tags: c#

I got 2 panels with textboxes and labels.I am trying to make the sum of panel1.texbox1*panel2.textbox1 + panel1.textbox2... and so on.But when I am running the program it actually shows me the product of all the textboxes.

Here I have the code for creating textboxes and labels:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int j,c=1;
    int i = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    if (i != null)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            Label label = new Label();

            label.Text = "w" + c;
            label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 20 + (20 * c));
            label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 20);
            panel1.Controls.Add(label);
            Label label2 = new Label();
            label2.Text = "x" + c;
            label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 20 + (20 * c));
            label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 20);
            panel3.Controls.Add(label2);
            TextBox w = new TextBox();
            w.Text = "";
            w.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 20 + (20 * c));
            w.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 20);
            panel1.Controls.Add(w);

            TextBox x = new TextBox();
            x.Text = "";
            x.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 20 + (20 * c));
            x.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 20);
            panel3.Controls.Add(x);

            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code that I tried to use:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int suma = 0;
    foreach (Control w1 in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {                            
        foreach (Control w2 in panel3.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            int textB1 = int.Parse(w1.Text);
            int textB2 = int.Parse(w2.Text);
            int textB3 = textB1 * textB2;
        }       
    }
    textBox3.Text = "" + suma;  
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged and checked the values that you're expecting vs the values that you are receiving?

Comment: If you want tb1 * tb1 + tb2*tb2 etc - assuming both panels contain the same number of controls you should replace your loops (both) with `for (int i = 0; i < panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Count; i++)` and then the actual arithmetic can just be `int textB1 = int.Parse(panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()[i];` and the second one is the same but panel 3.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Did it, getting different numbers.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Well,when i`m trying to make textB1 I get this error on Parse : ,,The best overloaded method match for int.Parse(string) has some invalid arguments",maybe you can help me?

Comment: Your casting is wrong, you are also casting labels to Textbox, please see my answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one line with linq, but you'll of course have to check for valid input in the text boxes first:

```
  var panel1Texts = panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
  var panel2Texts = panel2.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();

  Func<TextBox, bool> isInvalid = (text) =>
  {
    int res;
    return !int.TryParse(text.Text, out res);
  };

  var errorText = panel1Texts.FirstOrDefault(isInvalid);
  if (errorText != null)
  {
    // Error handling
  }

  errorText = panel2Texts.FirstOrDefault(isInvalid);
  if (errorText != null)
  {
    // Error handling
  }

  var sum = panel1Texts.Zip(panel2Texts, (tb1, tb2) => int.Parse(tb1.Text) * int.Parse(tb2.Text)).Sum();

textBox3.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code you are casting all your controls including your labels to textbox by doing `OfType<TextBox>()` on them as the collection also included labels.

Here is what i think you should do :

```
 TextBox3.Text = (Panel1.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)).Sum(v => int.Parse(v.Text)) + Panel2.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)).Sum(z => int.Parse(z.Text))).ToString();
```

Comment: The result is still wrong,thanks for the tip by the way.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you're expecting to get ?

Comment: so If in panel1 I type: 1
                                3

and in panel2 I type: 2

                              4

I should get: 14 (1*2+3*4)

Comment: You mean you type 1 3 in the same textbox of panel 1?

Comment: No,I am generating 2 textboxes in each panel

Comment: But the code should work, can you tell me what's wrong with it ? Do you get errors? Sry im writing on phone doing my best.

Comment: I am getting a different result,48 to be more precise.

Comment: Well the code sums up the value of any textboxes it can fond within the panel, doesn't do anything special to them tbh... can you check your ui once more?

Comment: i think i know what was wrong with it to i made the changes, let me know if u could check this.